# Looking for a line chart drill down to area chart using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, linechart

What i am exactly looking for is to implement a line chart comparing two brands and when i click on the individual line it has to drill down to a area chart since i am a beginner i javascript i m looking for snippets which can help me

http://jsfiddle.net/phdjsep/vNfWk/

something like this but instead of the bar chart in the first position i would like to have a "line chart" comparing two brands and instead of the line chart in the second i would like to have the "area chart"

```
code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution, which is line and deeper level - `area chart`.

http://jsfiddle.net/JPzqn/81/